Is there any fastify.addHook('onClose', () => {}) equivalent in Express Js?
As for the question, I'm trying to do some stuffs when the application is about to exit. Are there any express hooks or any solution to make the job done?
I tried something like this process.on('exit', function () { console.log('About to exit.'); }); but I'm still looking for other ways to do it.


There is another event you can listen to: beforeExit.

process.on('beforeExit', (code) => {
  console.log('Before exit: code ', code);
});


Other standard signals to listen to, like SIGTERM
process.on('SIGTERM', (code) => {...

